# Generating monthly report based on unix timestamps in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if this is a noob php/mysql question.

I have a database where each entry has a unix timestamp associated to it.

Lets say it has a structure like

| UniqueID | TimeStamp | Item | Buy | Sell

And lets say it has entries spanning a few years.

I would like to generate reports for each month lets say to count each item.

What is the best way of doing this in PHP/Mysql ?

Thanks !

Comment: you can have a cron job that runs a php script every month that gets the data from the database in the range of dates you specify and write it to a file. Are you looking for the actual code to have this done? in MySQL you can run queries that compare dates in a where clause

Comment: yeah but is there any intelligent api in mysql/php to convert a UnixTimestamp into a month ?  The way I was thinking is have the php script calculate what each month and then create a loop so that it pulls out the data for each month. But I was wandering if there is a more obvious solution (I am not really php programmer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to generate reports directly in SQL with statements like:

```
SELECT MONTH(TimeSTamp), Item, COUNT(Buy), COUNT(Sell) FROM your_table GROUP BY MONTH(TimeStamp), Item
```

which would list Items buys and sells by month. You can run this statement in PHP using e.g. @mysql_query (check the php manual for your php version).

If you need to convert from UNIX to another time format check out php function getdate.

Comment: yeah I had to use the FROM_UNIXTIME() and all was sweet

Answer (score 0):

I probably would not take this route but to do what you want I would convert the timestamps into DateTime objects and do whatever I needed with them. I will use a timestamp as an example

```
<?php
    $time = time();//Get a timestamp. This is just for an example, you will assign the value of your timestamp here
    $date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$time));
    echo $date->format('M'); //Prints out the month from the unix timestamp
?>
```

You can get the date directly from the date() function, but you have a lot of flexibility when you use the DateTime object

Comment: in mysql I found you can use FROM_UNIXTIME()